# Google Map API v3 in Show in Emulator

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, google-maps-api-3

I am creating a map using points from a server and setting them as markers, I then use the points to form a boundary, using Google Map API v3. The map displays properly in a desktop browser, but not in an emulator; it will not show the markers or boundary and will display some error like `Object is Not a function`, so I'm confused what the problem is.

In my code I put some `alerts`, `try-catch statements` and some error when the code tries to put boundary

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="lib/work-space.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/hsmobile.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #map-canvas
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="ClubMapPage">
    <script>
        $('#ClubMapPage').on('pageshow',function(){
            Mappy.getMappy();
        })
    </script>

    <div class="content-wrap map-wrap">
        <div id="map-canvas" style="height:500px; width:100%; margin:0; padding:0">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for showing google map v2 and v3 we need google services which not avialable for emulator or not installed so emultor can't show map...

Comment: do you have any example of it? @Haresh

Comment: what kind of example ???

Comment: In which we can use Google Map i seen some built project that showed map in emulator but i have not its source code

Comment: I think those project are not build with map v2 and v3 other wise it's not possible to show map.

Comment: This information is not correct. It is very possible to use the google maps api with the emulator, because it is a JavaScript library. If you want to use the Android Google Maps API, then yes, you must have the play services loaded.

Comment: i use Google Map JavaScript V3 and it works in browser but when i tested in emulator then i got error at this line `bermudaTriangle.setMap(mapObject);` that `Object is Not a function` 
@netinept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi here is an [article](http://www.christianengvall.se/phonegap-and-google-maps/) about `Google Map` With `PhoneGap` and the source code is available [here](https://github.com/crilleengvall/Phonegap-GoogleMap-and-ProjectSettings-example)